# Regex not able to show chars after space

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to break this string into two parts

```
{[data1]name=NAME1}{[data2]name=NAME2}

1) {[data1]name=NAME1}
2){[data2]name=NAME2}
```

I am using Regex to attain this and this works fine with the above string , but if i add space to the name then the regex does not take characters after the space.

```
{[data1]name=NAME 1}{[data2]name=NAME 2}
```

In this string it breaks only till NAME and does not show the 1 and 2 chars

This is my code

```cpp
    std::string stdstrData = "{[data1]name=NAME1}{[data2]name=NAME2}"
    std::vector<std::string> commandSplitUnderScore;
    std::regex re("\\}");
        std::sregex_token_iterator iter(stdstrData.begin(), stdstrData.end(), re, -1);
        std::sregex_token_iterator end;
    
        while (iter != end) {
            if (iter->length()) {
                commandSplitUnderScore.push_back(*iter);
            }
            ++iter;
        }
    
    
    for (auto& str : commandSplitUnderScore) {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start is to use regex101.com and debug your regex before putting it into your c++ code. e.g. https://regex101.com/r/ID6OSj/1 (don't forget to escape your C++ string properly when copying the regex you made on that site).
Example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>


int main()
{
    std::string input{ "{[data]name=NAME1}{[data]name=NAME2}" };
    std::regex  rx{ "(\\{\\[data\\].*?\\})(\\{\\[data\\].*?\\})" };
    std::smatch match;

    if (std::regex_match(input, match, rx))
    {
        std::cout << match[1] << "\n"; // match[1] is first group
        std::cout << match[2] << "\n"; // match[2] is second group
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The data text will not be same for all the strings , i have  changed that in my question.

Comment: Ok it will just require a small change to the regex. Do you want key/value pairs?
https://regex101.com/r/fFAGxl/1 and then you will have 6 groups to check, and this will also work with spaces in values (and keys)

Comment: check link again : https://regex101.com/r/fFAGxl/1 (updated)

Comment: @Pepjin Kramer Thanks based on your answer i am able to get the correct Regex.

Comment: That was the whole idea, happy coding :)